# Workflow Issue in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, workflow

All of a sudden Workflows aren't working in our SharePoint 2013 environment.

Its display "Not Started" as Internal Status and initiators as "anonymous"

I checked the events log and found the below message:

```
****************************************************
```

> Log Name:      Microsoft-Workflow/Operational Source:
>   Microsoft-Workflow Date:          10/24/2017 12:34:14 AM Event ID:
>   358 Task Category: (65176) Level:         Error Keywords:
>   Dispatcher User:          domain\serviceAccount Computer:
>   serverName Description: Dispatcher encountered an unexpected
>   exception: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred.
>   ---> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values. Parameter name: value    at
>   Microsoft.Workflow.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult
>   result)    at
>   Microsoft.Activities.Hosting.HostedHttpExtension.HttpRequestWorkItem.OnEndComplete(ScheduledWorkItemContext
>   context, IAsyncResult result)    at
>   Microsoft.Activities.Hosting.ScheduledWorkItem.EndComplete(ScheduledWorkItemContext
>   context, IAsyncResult result)    at
>   Microsoft.Activities.Dispatcher.DispatchLoopInstanceAsyncResult.SingleNonTransactionalWorkItemComplete(IAsyncResult
>   result)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   Microsoft.Activities.Dispatcher.DispatchLoopInstanceAsyncResult.UpdateNonTransactionalWork()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Activities.Dispatcher.DispatchLoopInstanceAsyncResult.Isolate(AsyncCompletion
>   callback, IAsyncResult result)    at
>   Microsoft.Activities.Dispatcher.DispatchLoopInstanceAsyncResult.SingleNonTransactionalWorkItemComplete(IAsyncResult
>   result)
>   ---> (Inner Exception #0) System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values. Parameter
>   name: value    at
>   Microsoft.Workflow.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult
>   result)    at
>   Microsoft.Activities.Hosting.HostedHttpExtension.HttpRequestWorkItem.OnEndComplete(ScheduledWorkItemContext
>   context, IAsyncResult result)    at
>   Microsoft.Activities.Hosting.ScheduledWorkItem.EndComplete(ScheduledWorkItemContext
>   context, IAsyncResult result)    at
>   Microsoft.Activities.Dispatcher.DispatchLoopInstanceAsyncResult.SingleNonTransactionalWorkItemComplete(IAsyncResult
>   result)<---
>
> ---> (Inner Exception #1) System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values. Parameter
>   name: value    at
>   Microsoft.Workflow.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult
>   result)    at
>   Microsoft.Activities.Hosting.HostedHttpExtension.HttpRequestWorkItem.OnEndComplete(ScheduledWorkItemContext
>   context, IAsyncResult result)    at
>   Microsoft.Activities.Hosting.ScheduledWorkItem.EndComplete(ScheduledWorkItemContext
>   context, IAsyncResult result)    at
>   Microsoft.Activities.Dispatcher.DispatchLoopInstanceAsyncResult.SingleNonTransactionalWorkItemComplete(IAsyncResult
>   result)<---
>
> Event Xml: 
>   
>       
>       358
>       0
>       2
>       65176
>       0
>       0x4000000000000200
>       
>       508680
>       
>       
>       Microsoft-Workflow/Operational
>       ServerName
>             
>       System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified
>   argument was out of the range of valid values. Parameter name: value
>   at
>   Microsoft.Workflow.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult
>   result)    at
>   Microsoft.Activities.Hosting.HostedHttpExtension.HttpRequestWorkItem.OnEndComplete(ScheduledWorkItemContext
>   context, IAsyncResult result)    at
>   Microsoft.Activities.Hosting.ScheduledWorkItem.EndComplete(ScheduledWorkItemContext
>   context, IAsyncResult result)    at
>   Microsoft.Activities.Dispatcher.DispatchLoopInstanceAsyncResult.SingleNonTransactionalWorkItemComplete(IAsyncResult
>   result)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   Microsoft.Activities.Dispatcher.DispatchLoopInstanceAsyncResult.UpdateNonTransactionalWork()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Activities.Dispatcher.DispatchLoopInstanceAsyncResult.Isolate(AsyncCompletion
>   callback, IAsyncResult result)    at
>   Microsoft.Activities.Dispatcher.DispatchLoopInstanceAsyncResult.SingleNonTransactionalWorkItemComplete(IAsyncResult
>   result)
>   ---> (Inner Exception #0) System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values. Parameter
>   name: value    at
>   Microsoft.Workflow.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult
>   result)    at
>   Microsoft.Activities.Hosting.HostedHttpExtension.HttpRequestWorkItem.OnEndComplete(ScheduledWorkItemContext
>   context, IAsyncResult result)    at
>   Microsoft.Activities.Hosting.ScheduledWorkItem.EndComplete(ScheduledWorkItemContext
>   context, IAsyncResult result)    at
>   Microsoft.Activities.Dispatcher.DispatchLoopInstanceAsyncResult.SingleNonTransactionalWorkItemComplete(IAsyncResult
>   result)<---
>
> ---> (Inner Exception #1) System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values. Parameter
>   name: value    at
>   Microsoft.Workflow.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult
>   result)    at
>   Microsoft.Activities.Hosting.HostedHttpExtension.HttpRequestWorkItem.OnEndComplete(ScheduledWorkItemContext
>   context, IAsyncResult result)    at
>   Microsoft.Activities.Hosting.ScheduledWorkItem.EndComplete(ScheduledWorkItemContext
>   context, IAsyncResult result)    at
>   Microsoft.Activities.Dispatcher.DispatchLoopInstanceAsyncResult.SingleNonTransactionalWorkItemComplete(IAsyncResult
>   result)<---

---

Please let me know what is this GUID for ?

```
<Provider Name="Microsoft-Workflow" Guid="{B2885F6E-231C-43FF-BBEA-7516148FF6FE}" />
```

Comment: Above GUID is a workflow GUID. Any idea how to identify a workflow based on GUID.